# Remote connection Azure SQL Server not showing All databases

Tags: database, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-vm

When I connect my `Azure SQL Server` using `Azure` portal then it shows me all `databases`  (shown in the screenshot1)

[image]

But when I connect to the same server using `SSMS` inside `Azure VM` then it shows only one `database` (shown in the screenshot2)

[image]

Please someone help me in this issue

Comment: Probably your user doesn't have read access to all the databases but to only one

Comment: No, I am the owner of the subscription, the server, and the databases. everything on this account

Comment: Hi @Muhammad Waheed, please correct me if I understand you wrong in the answer.

Comment: Hi @Muhammad Waheed Can it work now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you'd better check the `Options` settings, did you specify the db name. If so, you will only can see specified db, not all.

[image]